iTerm: remove box around commands
I recently updated iTerm and played a bit with its settings and some other CLI tools.
The end result is that iTerm decorates each command with a "hot box" that consents to select the command and generate smart links.

I would like to remove this behaviour: any idea?

Welcome to Ask Different.  Your macOS version probably isn’t important but the exact version and build of iterm might be good to edit in - there have been a fork or two in that program so people might be disinclined to offer an answer if you’re on a different version than their experience.

From the iTerm2 3.5.0 Change log:

You can click a command to select it. Search,
Filter, and Select All will then be restricted
to the selected command. You can disable this
feature in Settings > General > Selection.

Uncheck "Clicking on a command selects it to restrict Find and Filter"

Oh God, thanks!

That's really awesome!
